# колличество постов в зависимости от страницы wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

я вывожу посты в категории и указываю кол-во обычным образом указывая "posts_per_page"

```
$qargs = array(

    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'order'             => 'DSC',
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'posts_per_page'    => 12,
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'cat'               => $cat,
    'meta_query'        => array( 'relation' => 'AND', $meta )

            );
```

как можно сделать что бы только на первой странице выводилось 6 постов, а на всех остальных уже по 12?

пробовал так:

```
        if ($paged == 0) {

            $posts_per_page =  6;

            } else {
                $posts_per_page =  12;
            }
```

но тогда не правильно считает... нужно что бы на первой странице выводило 6 постов и со второй счититало уже с 7 и так далее. а у меня естественно получается что со второй страницы начинает считать с 13 поста...

Comment: Вам нужно для второй и последующих страниц изменить стандартный ofsset на свой, который будет добавлять +6 к стандартному. Делается это с помощью хуков, документация https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination

Comment: спасибо за ссылку, разобрался.